# How to do nested subplots in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe

I have a data set like this:

**Sample Dataframe:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

I only know how to generate individual plot:

```
for k, m in zip('ABCD', 'mbry'):
    plt.figure(k)
    for i in range(5):
        plt.subplot(5,1,i+1) 
        plt.bar(range(20), df[k][20*i: 20*(i+1)], color = m)
    plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)

plt.show()
```

How can I plot all four figures in the same page?

**This is what I want:**
[image]

---

**Update on 8/2/2017:**

I would also like to apply it to larger datasets. Here is @Phlya's code I tried but it doesn't give me what I want:

**A larger dataset:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 11)), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJK'))

from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import axes_grid

f = plt.figure()
for i, (k, m) in enumerate(zip('ABCDEFGHIJK', 'mbrygrygybr')):
    ag = axes_grid.Grid(f, 261+i, (5, 1), axes_pad=0)
    for j in range(5):
        ag[j].bar(range(20), df[k][20*j: 20*(j+1)], color = m)
        ag[j].set_ylim(0, df.max().max())
        if i%2==0:
            if j == 4:
                ag[j].yaxis.set_ticks([0, ag[j].get_yticks()[-1]])
            else:
                ag[j].yaxis.set_ticks([ag[j].get_yticks()[-1]])
        else:
            ag[j].yaxis.set_ticks([])

        if i in (0, 1):
            ag[j].xaxis.set_ticks([])

plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.5, hspace=0.5)
plt.show()
```

This dataset has 11 sets of data and clearly you can see the code made a mistake:
[image]

Comment: What does ```plt.figure``` do?

Comment: @wwii Sorry, I didn't make it clear in my original post. I want to get the same plots as my code gives me. But I want them to be in the same page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Complete rewrite.**

Axesgrid is what you want, I think.

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import axes_grid
nrows = 2
ncols = 6
naxes = 5
f = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
for i, (k, m) in enumerate(zip('ABCDEFGHIJK', 'mbrygrygybr')):
    ag = axes_grid.Grid(f, (nrows, ncols, i+1), (naxes, 1), axes_pad=0)
    for j in range(naxes):
        ag[j].bar(range(20), df[k][20*j: 20*(j+1)], color = m)
        ag[j].set_ylim(0, df.max().max())
        if i%ncols==0:
            if j == naxes-1:
                ag[j].yaxis.set_ticks([0, ag[j].get_yticks()[-1]])
            else:
                ag[j].yaxis.set_ticks([ag[j].get_yticks()[-1]])
        else:
            ag[j].yaxis.set_ticks([])
        if i in range(ncols):
            ag[j].xaxis.set_ticks([])

plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.1, hspace=0.1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

**EDITED:**
Nice ticks and spacing

**EDITED:**
Now should work well with arbitrary number of grids.
The main problem was with specification of the grid location when i>9.

Comment: @Kevin Glad I could help! Please also see my new edit to make nice ticks and identical y limits in all plots (assuming this is what you want).

Comment: Hi Phlya, I got some issue when I tried to plot 11 sets of data on a 2 x 6 supbplots. Only ten sets of data are displayed and the position and the shape of the last panel are wrong. Could you please help me look into it? [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yuyvcf8viaiuu8a/Unknown.png?dl=0). Thank you!

Comment: Please see the new version!

Comment: Do you also know how to set the title per axes_grid?

Comment: Maybe adding a title to the top axes in the grid?

Comment: @zwep yep, adding `ag[0].set_title(k)` before the inner for-loop works (might want to add bigger `hspace` though, 0.15 here). https://yadi.sk/i/G2gogvwur2EO4w

Comment: @Phlya Ah yes, so from that I understand that there is no title option for the whole axes-group.

Comment: @zwep I don't think there is one.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate the axes using

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2)
```

This will generate single figure with 4 `Axes` objects the way you want. Work with each `Axes` object by accessing the 2D array `ax`. For example, the top left plot is `ax[0][0]`.

Comment: The OP needs 5 axes instead of each one of the axes from your suggestion.